# Cant replace all the word with replacement in python based on the match in dictionary list

Tags: python, dictionary

I tried to replace the word in a string with the value in a dictionary if its matched.

My code:

```
test_dict = {"valuation": "none", "other": "test"}
for word, replacement in test_dict.items():
    if word in "other valuation $$$":
        strValue = "other valuation $$$".replace(word, replacement)
```

My current output:

```
'test valuation $$$'
```

My expected output:

```
'test none $$$'
```

is there a way to do it in single line? If not any types is fine.

Comment: You need to move `strValue`'s creation outside of the loop, because here you will always be using `"other valuation $$$"` as the string you're performing `replace` on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you change the `strValue` value back to the initial string.

```
test_dict = {"valuation": "none", "other": "test"}
strValue = "other valuation $$$"
for word, replacement in test_dict.items():
    strValue = strValue.replace(word, replacement)
print(strValue)
```

You can do the same in one line also but it also makes list with None values.

```py
test_dict = {"valuation": "none", "other": "test"}
strValue = ["other valuation $$$"]


[strValue.append(strValue[-1].replace(word,replacement)) for word,replacement in test_dict.items()]

print(strValue[-1])
```

output

```
test none $$$
```

Comment: Thank you. I am wondering is there a solution with one line?

Comment: This works fine without if statement too.